# How does GMail display the sidebar?

Tags: gmail

You know, like the "Compose Mail," "Inbox," "Sent Mail," etc., on the left hand-side when you load up GMail? I did a search for "Compose Mail" in the page source and got nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gmail interface uses JavaScript to dynamically load a lot of stuff. That explains why you don't see "Compose Mail".

If you want to see how the final HTML document looks like, then here is my method:

Install the "Web developer" Firefox extension

Click Tools> Web Developer> View Source> View Generated Source

Comment: +1 although I do recommend Firebug over the Web Developer extension. I have both but I rarely use WD for anything anymore, Firebug is just so much more useful.

Comment: Indeed. I also use both of them :-)

Comment: How come I still cannot find "Compose Mail" in the generated HTML?

Answer (score 2):

It's all Javascript. Here's how you can get at that information yourself: if you don't already use Firefox, download it, and then install the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) extension. Among other features, it'll let you click on any component of the page and show you the corresponding location in the source - not just the original page source, but the source *after* all the Javascript has taken effect.

Actually, if you use Internet Explorer, the IE Developer Toolbar (included in IE 8) does something similar, although I haven't used it much myself.

Comment: How come I still cannot find "Compose Mail" in the generated HTML? Raoul doesn't know either :(

Comment: No idea, I found it just fine using Firebug's "Inspect" tool. (It's the mouse-cursor-over-the-box icon next to the bug at the top left of Firebug when on the HTML tab)

Comment: +1 Firebug shows it whereas Web Developer does not. I wonder what makes the HTML sources different.